# user-specific vs all-machine pip install

Tags: linux, python, pip

When I `pip install` as just any user, things get installed specifically for me; but if I do it as root, they get installed for the entire system (e.g. in `/usr/local/bin`).

How can I make this choice explicitly? i.e.

1. As a non-root user, indicate I want a system-level install and get prompted for the root password.
2. As a root user, install something just for myself under `/root`.

Answer (score 0):

For item 2, the following should work (as root):

```
# pip --user install some_thing_to_install
```

Not sure about option 1 though.